# find angle from given side of right andgle triangle and vise versa in c#

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry

I have right angle triangle and a adjutant side is known to me now i want to make user enter either angle or opposite side and based on adjutant side and other entered parameter third parameter got calculated i have tried this given way but it is not returning true results for opposite side

```
oppositeside= Math.Tan(Convert.ToDouble(angle) * Math.PI / 180.0) * adjustantside;
```

and for angle i have tried following way

```
angle = Math.Atan(oppositeside * adjustantside)*180/Math.PI;
```

But it is not working does anyone khow how to do it in right way?

Comment: Further this: `angle = Math.Atan(oppositeside * adjustantside)*180/Math.PI;` must be a division not a multiplication inside the atan: `angle = Math.Atan(oppositeside / adjustantside)*180/Math.PI;` because `tan A = opp./adj.`.

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"? Are you asking for the math formula?

Comment: yes sir i want a working math formula in c#

Comment: I want to simply that i have adjestant side of right triangle now weather user enters angle then it will calculate opposite side and if user enters opposite side then it will calculate angle

Answer (score 2):

> but it is not returning true results for opposite side

Actually it does, but you have to input `angle` in degrees:

```
double adjustantside = 0.5;
int angle = 45;
oppositeside= Math.Tan(Convert.ToDouble(angle) * Math.PI / 180.0) * adjustantside;
```

> Output: 0.5

In a unity circle (hypothenuse = length of 1) the `adjustantside` will be equal to the `oppositeside` at an angle of `45°`.

The tangent is calculated the following way:

[image]

taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#tangent)

So your calculation should look like this:

```
angle = Math.Atan(oppositeside / adjustantside)*180/Math.PI;
```

PS. the radiant conversion with `* Math.PI / 180.0` is correct: see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian):

[image]